# Extracting other column value based on lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one large row of data, containing multiple observations. The data consits of:
PO number
Amount
Location

See attached image:

[image]

Now what I want is that PO Number 8382 (A2) is looked up in A8:L8 and puts in B2 the amount of each PO number and puts in C2 the location. So what it needs to do, is lookup a value in the row and extract the value on the right of it. I tried H.lookup but that did not work.

Can anyone help me? I used index and match, but I can't make it work. I believe it's probably a simple question but I can't figure it out.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is correct.

In cell B2:

`=INDEX($A$8:$L$8,1,MATCH($A2,$A$8:$L$8,0)+1)`

In cell C2:

`=INDEX($A$8:$L$8,1,MATCH($A2,$A$8:$L$8,0)+2)`

Copy down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (It find first occurence in ROW 8)

- Cell B2 formula `=OFFSET($A$1;1;MATCH($A2;8:8;0);1;1)`
- Cell C2 formula `=OFFSET($A$1;1;MATCH($A2;8:8;0)+1;1;1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(8,MATCH(A6,$A$8:$H$8,0)+1)),"PO not found")
```

using IFERROR you avoid receiving errors if any of the PO not found.

[image]